# Javascript Event Delegation

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

Im trying to rewrite the following function for event delegation:

```
$("ul > li.closed").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    }
});
```

All the other functions I've rewritten run perfectly, but this one doesn't. Here is what I wrote:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul > li.closed", function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    }
});
```

As you can see, I didn't really change a lot. The ul opens, but doesn't close anymore. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try `$("ul").on("click", "li.closed", function (e) {`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is once the `li` is opened, the class `closed` is removed and `open` is added, which means the the selector `li.closed` does not match

In the case of event delegation the selectors are evaluated lazily, but in case of normal event handling the handlers are registered to the target element at the time of the event registration so at that time which ever element had the class `closed` will get the handler

```
$(document).on("click", "ul > li:has(ul)", function (e) {
    var li = $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    li.children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference?

Comment: This opens the li and closes it directly. Only after another click it behaves like intended.